# How to put XML values of child nodes into an array and return this array?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a XML and want to read values from only specific child nodes. Then I want to put those read values into an array and return this array at the end. So I want to get all values of name saved in an array and return this array. In the end, I want to display all values of this array beneath each other in an HTML file.

Here is my idea so far (which does not work obviously):

```php
$items= simplexml_load_file('https://example.com/xml');
$itemList = array();
foreach ($items as $item->name) {
   // Push the values of name of the item nodes into an array
}
return $itemList;
```

Here is the structure of the XML file:

```xml
<item>
   <name>Name 1</name>
</item>
<item>
   <name>Name 2</name>
</item>
<item>
   <name>Name 3</name>
</item>
<item>
   <name>Name 4</name>
</item>
```

Comment: Please complete your question by describing how it doesn't work.  Are you displaying anything? Nothing? Errors? Warnings? Notices?

Comment: Edited. I want do display the values in a HTML file. But in the end, this does a parser which is the reason why I have to return sth.

Comment: If my solution doesn't work please let me know so that I can adjust.

Comment: Would be great if it is possible to only return the values like Name 1, Name 2 etc. beneath each other.

Comment: So just `echo impode("<br>", $names);` then.  This is super basic programming.

Comment: Yes it is. Echo is clear to me. But for the parser I am using there has to be a return value.

Comment: So then `return $names;`. I don't understand the challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over each item and take it's `name` property. Explicitly cast `name` property to `string`, cause by default `$item->name` is **not** a string:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
   $itemList[] = (string)$item->name;
}
```

Comment: And how do I return this array or the values of this array? When I do return $itemList nothing gets displayed. Yes, I have to because I it has to work in a specific parser (Statamic).

Comment: What do you mean by "return"? You could of course simply `return $itemList`. If you need data exchange with a different language or system, you might want to convert this array into a JSON string: `echo json_encode($itemList);`?

Comment: `return` is used inside a `function` usually. I don't see function in your code. If there's a fuction - just use `return $itemList;` as the last line of your function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `foreach()` code as well as do assignment inside it:-

```
$itemList = array();
foreach ($items as $item) { //$item->name will not work here
   $itemList[] = $item->name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` for converting xml data to string data type. After that, which tag you want to use, you can use this tag in `foreach()` loop. And after that, you should to create an empty array and insert all string data to empty array.

```
    $items = simplexml_load_file('https://example.com/xml');
    $json = json_encode($items);
    $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

    $names = array();
    foreach ($array["item"] as $key => $value) {
      $names[] = $value["name"];
    }


    print_r($names);
```

Result:

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Name 1
    [1] => Name 2
    [2] => Name 3
    [3] => Name 4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't do a lot of xml processing, so I tried the earlier posted answers (and the answer that came after I posted) with your sample xml and they didn't work for me.

I managed to process your data by writing your xml inside of a parent element before parsing, then looping and casting the name as a string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/A0MSY))

```
$xml = <<<XML
<item>
   <name>Name 1</name>
</item>
<item>
   <name>Name 2</name>
</item>
<item>
   <name>Name 3</name>
</item>
<item>
   <name>Name 4</name>
</item>
XML;
foreach (simplexml_load_string("<root>{$xml}</root>")->item as $item) {
   $names[] = (string)$item->name;
}
var_export($names);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Name 1',
  1 => 'Name 2',
  2 => 'Name 3',
  3 => 'Name 4',
)
```